# Preg Replace with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

Okay so heres what I have but whenever I do this, I am returned with the first record of the database:

```
<?php
    function getInfo($id,$slot){
        if(!$id){ return '<b>Error</b> Id Not Returned. Please contact support@site.com for more information.'; }
        $mm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$id."'");
        $mma = mysql_fetch_assoc($mm);
        $p = $mma[$slot];
        return $p;
        //return $id; <- Debug (Returns ID given)
    }
$post = preg_replace("/\[CallName]([^]]+)\[\/CallName\]/", getInfo('\\1',"fullname"), $post);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised you're getting anything returned...your preg_replace pattern should be giving you an error (you aren't escaping some of your brackets). But anyways, you can't pass a captured group to your function like that.  You have to use the "e" pattern modifier (look at example #4 in the [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) manual